# Django view with variable form name

Tags: django, forms, variables, instantiation

I was interested in using same view for multiple forms depending on the Project that is being viewed.
Not sure why i can't sort this out, might be a 'forest for the trees' issue.

I have an app with various Projects and each project has a separate ModelForm.  I wanted to use the same view to display each form based on a Project ID that is passed in.

My attempt was to put a form_name CharField in the Project which holds the name of the form - project.form_name="project_specific_form" .  When the view is called a Project ID is passed in.  I tried replacing the standard form call "a=SomeForm()" with "a=project.form()" to grab the specific form for that project.  That didn't work.  I also tried several versions of string concantonation to be used with 'exec' to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, this worked but it doesn't feel right.

form="a="+str(project.form)+'()'
exec form

Comment: Where are the form classes defined?

Comment: in the models.py file for the app.

Answer (score 1):

There's almost never a reason to use exec.

Define a method on the model to return the form. You can use the `globals()` function, which returns a dictionary of all module-level attributes:

```
class Project(model.Model):
    ...

    def get_form(self):
        form = globals()[self.form]
        return form
```

but I think a better way would be to define a module-level dictionary with all the forms:

```
project_forms = {
    'foo': FooForm
    'bar': BarForm
}

class Project(models.Model):
    def get_form(self):
        return project_forms[self.form]
```

Note that the dictionary's values are the actual form classes, not their names.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but how do I get around the referencing FooForm before it is assigned?  I just moved the forms into a forms.py, imported the models, and imported the forms into the models.py. But ran into a issue in forms because the ModelForm references a model in models.py it hasn't seen yet.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to reference it before it's assigned. If you want to use this pattern, I actually wouldn't move the forms into a separate module, otherwise you'll run into circular reference issue (forms.py and models.py both depend on each other). But if the definitions are at the end of models.py, along with the dictionary, you shouldn't have any problems.